# stream wrapper public /private not found Error

Tags: 7, stream-wrappers

Configuration : WAMP on windows drupal 7

I have tried using

```
$image = file_get_contents('E:\Team_Install\wamp\www\rootfolder\sites\all\modules\my_module\errorwinmobilesdk.jpg');
$file = file_save_data($image, 'public://',FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);
```

I can see the result after first line `file_get_contents` but on `file_save_data` I get that destination folder invalid error

Another method I had tried was  `$file = file_copy($source, $dest);`

here also it says $dest does not exists 
Wrapper folder permission and path are check thorughly they are working when I add an image using media_gallery module as it saves to public gallery or creates a new article with image, when I try to add from code it breaks and start showing message

> The data could not be saved because the destination public is
>   invalid. This may be caused by improper use of file_save_data() or a
>   missing stream wrapper.

Please help I am new to drupal and stuck at this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The 2nd param to `file_save_data` needs to be a stream wrapper path, e,g, `public://` instead of `public`

Comment: sry code was edited to try different version i did not corrected back , i had already tried with both "public://" or 'public' or event the complete path none worked , just corrected it

Comment: It's difficult to say exactly what's causing the problem without access to the file system - the best advice I can give is to start at [`field_valid_uri()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/function/file_valid_uri/7) (called from `file_save_data()`) and work your way down until you find out exactly what Drupal's objecting to

Comment: i have tried to drill down to code started from file_valid_uri() till  $wrappers = file_get_stream_wrappers(); file_get_stream_wrappers are returning blank array any idea as to whta can be the reason

Comment: "$image = file_get_contents('root\sites\all\modules\my_module\errorwinmobilesdk.jpg');
$directory = 'public://' ; 
$result = file_valid_uri($directory);
$uri_scheme = file_uri_scheme($directory);
print_r( $uri_scheme);
if (empty($uri_scheme) || !file_stream_wrapper_valid_scheme($uri_scheme)) {
echo  'file_stream_wrapper_scheme FALSE';
} 
$class = file_stream_wrapper_get_class($uri_scheme);
print_r('$class' . $class);
if (class_exists($class)) {
echo 'class_exists';
}
$wrappers = file_get_stream_wrappers();
print_r('$wrappers  ' . $wrappers );
echo '<pre>'; print_r($wrappers); echo '</pre>';

Comment: Print output  edited some print statement to adjust in the comment as there is limit "public://
public
file_stream_wrapper_valid_scheme FALSE 
$class ...................class_exists FALSE 
$wrappers Array...............
Array
(
)
"

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too after some coding with file_save_data. And i solve it after clearing the cache and resaving the path in the file system configuration at admin/config/media/file-system.

My problem comes from an add field of file type, programmatically in an update.